# search file for a particular string and check is there anything after

Tags: c#, .net

I want to check file content for a particular string, actually I want to check is file contains '`ANSWER`' and if there some character of anything after that string to the end of file.

How can I achive that?

p.s. file content is dynamic content and that 'ANSWER' string is not on fixed location inside file.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
static bool containsTextAfter(string text, string find)
{
    // if you want to ignore the case, otherwise use Ordinal or CurrentCulture
    int index = text.IndexOf(find, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase); 
    if (index >= 0)
    {
        int startPosition = index + find.Length;
        if (text.Length > startPosition)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

use it in this way:

```
bool containsTextAfterAnswer = containsTextAfter(File.ReadAllText("path"), "ANSWER");
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to load the entire file into memory and search it:

```
string s = File.ReadAllText(filename);
int pos = s.IndexOf("ANSWER");
if (pos >= 0)
{
    // we know that the text "ANSWER" is in the file.
    if (pos + "ANSWER".Length < s.Length)
    {
        // we know that there is text after "ANSWER"
    }
}
else
{
    // the text "ANSWER" doesn't exist in the file.
}
```

Or, you can use a regular expression:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(s, "ANSWER(.*)");
if (m.Success)
{
    // the text "ANSWER" exists in the file
    if (m.Groups.Count > 1 && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.Groups[1].Value))
    {
        // there is text after "ANSWER"
    }
}
else
{
    // the text "ANSWER" does not appear in the file
}
```

In the regex case, the position of "ANSWER" would be in `m.Index`, and the position of the text after "ANSWER" would be in `m.Groups[1].Index`.